# <object> transforms into a server-sent document having <script>, <table>, & mouse onevent code intended to return data to window.top

Tags: javascript, php, object

One of my web page elements is an <object> element with neither <iframe> nor any other container.  I'd be happiest if I can keep using it without a container because it works fine for everything but this my current task of getting a piece of data over to a <textarea> in the main part of the page. In particular <object> elements morph into text, HTML, image, or video styles according to the return from their URI, so I am forced to make the server send the client on event Javascript coding and some functions located in a <script> tag just prior to the <table> tag.

My difficulty: I have a <textarea>.value outside of this <object> called `StartTimeOfInterestEl.value`, that needs to display (after trimming and adjusting) a short string of character data located in a <td> of the table.

EDIT: An easier way of saying this is that the Javascript that comes in the URI needs to directly(?) set the static element `StartTimeOfInterestEl.value`, but indications are that there is a scope boundary between server-sent Javascript code and the static code.

Javascript static side:

```
function takeTimeOfInterest(timestmp)
{
    StartTimeOfInterestEl.value=timestmp             
}
```

Server-side script commands that I've tried:
`window.opener.takeTimeOfInterest(StartTimeOfInterest)`

or

`opener.document.takeTimeOfInterest(StartTimeOfInterest)`

or just

`takeTimeOfInterest(StartTimeOfInterest)`

and none of these execute the function to receive the data, as evidenced when I place an alert box in that function - no alert happens.  In fact, each of these causes code execution to end at that statement, proving to me that each trips an error.

The commands that execute on through without error seem to be commands that try to directly set `StartTimeOfInterestEl.value`, but though commands may not error to end execution, I haven't found one that actually does set that value successfully.

Is there some kind of scope boundary that exists between server-sent code and static code?  I'm obviously unsure of child, parent, and opener relationships in this scenario and have tried `window.opener` to get the server-sent code to execute global page functions, but the execution of code just will not cross from child to opener scope, if such scope difference exists.  And I'm unsure whether server-sent code is actually boundaries at a window level from the static page elements.

Could someone throw me a clue here that maybe is a specific method of using container-less <object>?  Thank you!

(Note the server-sent code is NOT generated by PHP but by bash script, so I just care about that aspect of code as the client will render it.  IOW, My PHP experience is way too little for me to translate it to bash that I need, so a PHP snippet won't help me here.)

Answer (score 0):

Got it.  Simple:
`window.top.StartTimeOfInterestEl.value=StartTimeOfInterest`  in the server-side code.